# chrome.windows.update limitations on window size

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I found out that chrome.windows.update imposes limitations on possible window sizes, passed through updateInfo parameter. If requested width or height of a window is larger than width or height of a screen/desktop, the function shrinks the values to the screen sizes. I'm not sure if this bug or feature. At least, this behaviour is not covered by the Chrome extensions documentation, and makes me think the function works not exactly as expected. Does someone found a workaround for this limitation, other than writing a plugin?

After a short test it turned out that the limitation is applied not by the extensions API, but by Chrome core itself. Even a plugin can't arbitrary change Chrome window size using, for example, WinAPI. Still need a workaround for this. The only thing I can think out so far is the top window subclassing, but I foresee some challenges on this way.

Comment: I do not think this is a bug - e.g. in Windows you can not resize any window to size larger than screen size.

Comment: This isn't exactly an extensions limitation - the user cannot make the window larger than the screen either.

Comment: Indeed so. Strangely I didn't notice this limitation for years. Should we close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved (at the time the question was posted) by NPAPI plugin which subclasses browser's windows and process [`WM_GETMINMAXINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages in such a way that default Windows' window size limits are extended up to required window sizes. For those who may be interested I should note, that Chrome will no longer support plugins in future.